# How to simply set alternate inequality conditions for numpy histogram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, histogram, inequality

According to the [example in the numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html),

```
>>> np.histogram([1, 2, 1], bins=[0, 1, 2, 3])
(array([0, 2, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

Looking at `1`, we notice there are two occurrences in the second bin, meaning the bins are taken to be the range `left <= x_i < right`. Suppose one wanted to switch this such that `left < x_i <= right`. Is there a simple way to do this in numpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.histogram()` uses `np.searchsorted(..., side='right')` to compute the bin number for each sample value. So you can do:

```
import numpy as np

data = [1, 2, 1]
bins = [0, 1, 2, 3]

hist = np.zeros(len(bins) - 1, dtype=int)
bin_numbers = np.searchsorted(bins, data, side='left')
for idx, val in zip(*np.unique(bin_numbers, return_counts=True)):
    hist[idx - 1] = val

result = hist, bins
```

`result` is:

```
(array([2, 1, 0]), [0, 1, 2, 3])
```